# Protractor Executing afterEach before the expect has occured

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is happening. Basically the 'it' test is running and executing correctly UNTIL the expect, at which point it jumps off the new page immediately and executes the afterEach statement. I've tried using browser.wait, .then, adding the afterEach into the 'it' browser.sleep etc and get the same result.

So does someone with more knowledge in protractor know how I can force it to execute the expect before running the afterEach?

```
 afterEach(function() {
    browser.get(browser.params.urls.base).then(function() {
        $('a[href="/Account/LogOff"]').click();
    });
 });

it('Should use the access code url and login to the content', function() {
    loginPage.registerWithAccessCode();
    loginPage.accessCodeExisting(accessCode, browser.params.user.email, browser.params.user.password);
    loginPage.accessCodeSubmit();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('pal/placementtest/welcome');     
});
```

Comment: Try writing expect in call back of submit button: loginPage.submitButton.click().then(function(){
    expect(element(by.id('viewbox').getText()).toContain('updated value');
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping this in a `describe`?

Try this structure:

```
describe('My login scenario', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    loginPage.registerWithAccessCode();
    // the rest of your "act" steps...
  });

  it('should...', function() {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('pal/placementtest/welcome');
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    // Logout
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, sorry Should of added that in, so moving afterEach after the it declarations?

Comment: Well, thats mostly for readability, since afterEach vill be executed last. It's wrapping your code in beforeEach that is important.